# Extract a vector from a list

Tags: r, list

I am trying to cleanly extract a vector from a list.

The code below provides that data that I want.  But it returns a list instead of a vector.

```
lst_demo <- list(a = c("a1", "a2", "a3"), b = c("b1", "b2"), 
                                                    c = "c1")
filter_code <- "b"
result <- lst_demo[names(lst_demo) == filter_code]
# result produces what I expect: "b1" , "b2"
result
# but I want the data type to be a vector rather than a list
class(result)
```

I understand that I can cast to a vector with `as.character` but I am looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Follow up: I understand that I can cast to a vector ("as.character") but I am looking for a cleaner solution

Comment: You can use `unlist(result)` to convert it to a character vector.

Comment: `lst_demo[[filter_code]]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not already added as an answer (but has been said by @thelatemail as a comment)

```
result <- lst_demo[[filter_code]]
class(result)
[1] "character"
```

is probably what you're after.

Comment: Not really sure why this is downvoted. It has attribution. If a commenter wanted to post an answer, he had 55 minutes to do so.

Comment: Just a copy/paste, even with attribution.

Comment: Actually, I came to the same solution, wrote out the answer properly to detail the consequence, and added the attribution. How else should I have written it?

Comment: If it's any consolation, I'm not worried. :-P